# Decrypt php encripted string with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, cryptojs

i need to decript my secret string generated from open_ssl php function with javascript.

I'm trying to decrypt string generated from php with cryptoJS

PHP FUNCTION

```
$encData = openssl_encrypt(utf8_encode($pure_string), 'DES-EDE3',$encryption_key , OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
$session['chip'] = base64_encode($encData);
```

JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION

```
var keyHex = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(secretkey);
// direct decrypt ciphertext
var decrypted = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(secretText)
    }, keyHex, {
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.ECB
    });
console.info('decrypted :', decrypted);
var plaintext = decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
console.info('plaintext :', plaintext);
```

But nothing to do, i'm not able to get right result.
I think that problem happen because php use EDE3 mode, and i haven't found any way to use that mode with cryptoJS.

Any suggestion or any other sample to decrypt DES-EDE3 string?

Thank you!